# How do I load a .txt file accessable by HTTP into a JavaScript array by lines?

Tags: javascript

I have a .txt file accessible by http (e.g. "http://foo.net/bar.txt", not actually a link). I'm trying to load it into a JavaScript array by lines using raw JavaScript, but no solution that anyone has posted seems to work. Or, rather, no solution that anyone's explained to the point where I can alter it effectively seems to work as I need it to.

Here's the two solutions I've found that, as explained, can be used with raw JavaScript.

```
var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        var dataURL = reader.result;
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        output.src = dataURL;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
};
```

and

```
function readTextFile(file){
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                alert(allText);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

Please note that neither of these solutions actually returns the text content of the text file, much less to an array with each cell of the array being an individual line of the text file. How can I accomplish this?

EDIT: Going with the second option, modified as follows:

```
function readTextFile(file){
    var allText;
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                allText = rawFile.responseText.split("\n");
                return allText;
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

...I get two errors.

```
Content Security Policy: Ignoring ‘x-frame-options’ because of ‘frame-ancestors’ directive.
```

and

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://foo.net/bar.txt. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Via the Debugger, I found that the program doesn't even step into the `onreadystatechange` part.

Comment: The second example will get you the contents of the file in `allText` (assuming same domain). Simply split that on the newline character.

Comment: FileReader() is for local resources so thats out. Your 2nd Ajax approach is the way to go - but it will only work if the URL is on the same domain at the page making the request or the remote URL has been specifically setup to allow cross-origin access.  What information is displayed in the browsers error console when the code fails?

Comment: @AlexK. Using my example url, the domain of the page making the request would be https://foo.net/user/user01/view/public/test.html. In the Console I find "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://foo.net/bar.txt. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)." and "Content Security Policy: Ignoring ‘x-frame-options’ because of ‘frame-ancestors’ directive."

Comment: @ObsidianAge Going through the browser's debugger, I found that allText is "" when the .txt file is over a hundred lines.

Comment: If by some chance this is node.js, then https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader is great. I've used it to do line-by-line stuff with txt files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your second example, you can convert it into an array by `.split`ting at `\n`s. `allText.split("\n")` will return an array of all the text seperated by newlines.

Your second example will only work if the address is on the same website the page is on or if it can get through CORS. This is for security because otherwise if you were signed into a page, another website could make you post things or do actions without your visiting that site.

To enable CORS for your site so you can access the text file, you can set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `*` in the response.

Comment: I like it. Nice answer.

Comment: reading a file from another domain let alone from another folder of the same domain has nothing to do with security - especially not that of a client - the cors is actually implemented on the client side by your browser vendor.: So that you would not be able to build desktop applications that would spare you from visiting several websites to get your information of interest in one place on demand without having to undergo what we're normally forced to.

Comment: It is done by the client to make sure you can't for example on another website send a post request to twitter to retweet a post, or access a text file on another server that is set to return your password. @BekimBacaj

Comment: that's not true at all you can't do that even if you have full access using ajax call because it requires server side processing.

Comment: Your client stores your cookies, so by sending a post request to twitter, your browser would send along your cookies as well. The server would see that it matches their cookies and accept the request

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but it doesn't work. The split part may, but the errors posted in comments still show up and this doesn't fix either of them. I'll edit the main question to include the errors.

Comment: @BrandonOlson Did you set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` header on your server for that file?

Comment: @pfg No, but I found the error. The server I'm running on is supposed to be accessed via http, not https. On the http version, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` is set. Thanks for the help!